# How do I find the eviction rate of keys in redis?

Tags: caching, redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli, redis-cache

My redis cluster is configured with `maxmem`.  The eviction policy is `allkeys-lru`.  I want to know how long the keys are lasting on average before they are evicted.  Every time a key is evicted, doesn't redis capture how long it lived for?

I was looking at INFO in redis-cli and I see these keyspace metrics:

```
# Keyspace
db5:keys=13502644,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

However, it seems that "avg_ttl" only corresponds to keys that expire; not keys that are evicted.
The only other relevant thing I can find are total counts:

```
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:17026842
```

Neither of these help me answer the question:  How long do keys normally last before they are evicted?